# How to create a border with spaces in it

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out how to use CSS to create the below effect.

I've tried to do this by creating 4 divs within a parent div and positioning them on all four sides.

This works, but breaks when I need those 4 divs to be transparent to the background and not a single color.

For example, I want to try to make this work again a picture background and not just a solid background.

If the background is solid I can make the 4 divs the same color as the background, the problem is that if the background is a picture I can't have the 4 divs match the background.

Also, I understand my fundamental approach to the problem might be wrong. I heard someone mentioning using a pseudo :before and :after to accomplish this effect for effectively, but I'm not sure how to do that.

[image]

Comment: You can make an image as background of a div and the text should be dynamic.

Comment: As @NaveedRamzan, you can use background image.

Comment: Instead of filling the 4 divs, just put a top, bottom, left or right border on them as disired. `background-color` can be set to `transparent` or left blank.

Comment: how to use background-image: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I made it as close as I could get with the least code:

```css
.daysleft {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px; 
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.daysleft span {
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

.white {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 20px;
    width: 101%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.daysleft:before {
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0;
}

.daysleft:after {
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 20px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="daysleft"><div class="white"></div><span>37 Days left</span></div>
```

EDIT:

Found a way to interupt the borders! Awnser updated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is the sort of thing you want.

```css
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ccc;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #333;
}
#content:before, #content:after, #content>:first-child:before, #content>:first-child:after {
    position:absolute;
    width:15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-color:#777;
    /* or whatever colour */
    border-style:solid;
    /* or whatever style */
    content:' ';
}
#content:before {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    border-width: 2px 0 0 2px
}
#content:after {
    top:0;
    right:0;
    border-width: 2px 2px 0 0
}
#content>:first-child:before {
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0
}
#content>:first-child:after {
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 2px
}
```

```html
  

<div class="container">
    <div id="content">
        <p><i>37</i> days left</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/5gjh6jkx/

Answer (score 1):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aminkodaganur/8bvyyda4/)
Try out this... here am using background as image

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
    37 days Left  
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
    background-color : #ccc;
    padding : 20px;
    width : 100%;
    margin : 0 auto;
}


.child
{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
text-align : center;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
border: 15px solid #ccc;
border-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WlsT.png') 34% repeat;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NrU34/52/)

**DEMO CODE**

**HTML**

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box1{
    position:relative;
    background:#FFF;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid 2px #090;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.box2{
    position:absolute;
    width:210px;
    height:180px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    top:10px;
    left:-5px;
}
.box3{
    position:absolute;
    width:180px;
    height:210px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    top:-5px;
    left:10px;
}
```